# Why ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exception' in python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I have a folder structure like this:

```
src/
|__ __init__.py
|__ exception.py
|__ logger.py
|__ components/
   |__ __init__.py
   |__ data_ingestion.py
```

both **init**.py are empty.

When I run the command "python src/components/data_ingestion.py", it gives me error:
[image]

Both **init**.py files are empty. When attempting to run the command "python src/components/data_ingestion.py," I encountered an error. The project consists of three main files: exception.py, logger.py, and data_ingestion.py. The data_ingestion.py file is trying to import classes from exception.py and logger.py.

Here the codes:

**exception.py**

```
import sys
from logger import logging

def error_message_detail(error,error_detail:sys):
    _,_,exc_tb = error_detail.exc_info()
    file_name = exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename

    error_message = "Error occured in python script name [{0}] line number [{1}] error message [{2}]".format(
        file_name, exc_tb.tb_lineno, str(error)
    )

    return error_message

class CustomException(Exception):
    
    def __init__(self, error_message, error_detail:sys):
        super().__init__(error_message)
        self.error_message = error_message_detail(error_message, error_detail=error_detail)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.error_message  
    

if __name__=="__main__":
    logging.info("Logging has started")

    try:
        a=1/0
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info('Division by zero') 
        raise CustomException(e,sys)
```

**logger.py**

```
import logging 
import os
from datetime import datetime

LOG_FILE=f"{datetime.now().strftime('%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S')}.log"
logs_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"logs",LOG_FILE)
os.makedirs(logs_path,exist_ok=True)

LOG_FILE_PATH=os.path.join(logs_path,LOG_FILE)

logging.basicConfig(
    filename=LOG_FILE_PATH,
    format="[ %(asctime)s ] %(lineno)d %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO
)

##### The below code is only for checking and not required
if __name__=="__main__":
    logging.info("Logging has started")
```

**data_ingestion.py**

```
from src.exception import CustomException
from src.logger import logging
```

Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run a script from within a (child) module, and this module is trying to call a function that is in its parent module. The child module doesn't know anything about the parent module in this scenario.

On the other hand, this import will work if you're running the app originally from the parent module.

Using your tree structure as an example, create a python file in the parent module:

```
src/
|__ __init__.py
|__ main.py  <== new file
|__ exception.py
|__ logger.py
|__ components/
   |__ __init__.py
   |__ data_ingestion.py
```

Then from `main.py` you will be able to call any functions that are inside `data_ingestion.py`, and they in turn will know about the functions inside `exception.py` and `logger.py`.

Comment: There is a same project with same folder structure and code that I coded 5-6 months ago. There data_ingestion.py is running without any issue. But problem is I have created this new project with same code as before, here it is not working. Why?

Comment: Probably not the same structure and code then.

Comment: Same structure and code.